# How can I recursively verify for nulls while navigating down an object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm using Powermock Mockito  1.5.1 with Java 1.7.

On testing a web service method, I need to check a certain value with in the response object. The problem is, this value is a few layers deep and I'll need to do `null` check on all its parent values before getting to the actual value in question.

Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
response = service.method1();
assertThat(response, notNullValue());
assertThat(response.getA(), notNullValue());
assertThat(response.getA().getB(), notNullValue());
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC(), notNullValue());
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC().getD(), notNullValue());
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC().getD().size(), is(1));
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC().getD().get(0), notNullValue());
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC().getD().get(0).value(), is("ABC"));
```

Is there a way to save out on all the `notNullValue()` validation code, but have it automatically happen. So can be something like:

```
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC().getD(), *recursivelyNotNull()*);
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC().getD().size(), is(1));
assertThat(response.getA().getB().getC().getD().get(0).value(), is("ABC"));
```

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of like mkdir with with -p tag, if parents doesn't exist, recursively create it (http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir). Where as in this case if any of the objects in the chain doesn't exist, then fail the test.

Answer (score 3):

### Just let the test throw a `NullPointerException`.

If you want to make sure that, down the chain, there's a value there, then the test will fail if it throws a `NullPointerException`.

That said, needing to chain that far down is a [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violation, and is probably a code smell. Perhaps you can break apart your unit tests further?

Answer (score 1):

So many people think java is ugly for NullPointer, and you can use Guava Optional avoid Null Object or upgrade jdk to 1.8 .

If not you should throw it at inner and try catch it at outermost layer.